# need to send html mail with attachment in unix

Tags: html, unix, sendmail

I am facing problems in sending html mail with attachemnt.I will able to send mail  with 
attachment (plain text ) using  mailx -s and uuencode  command and also html mail 
without attachment using sendmail option.

However I am not able to send html mail along with attachment.
Either one of it is working (html mail or attachment)

Below are the different ways I have tried. Could you please help me in resolving the same.

```
1)   Failed because of illegal option base64

#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="abc@abc.com"
export SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
export BODY="card_summary_mail.html"
export ATTACH="query5_result.csv"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo 'Content-Type: application; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode --base64 $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/lib/sendmail $MAILTO
```

---

```
2)  
cib-sokay2{u384283}323:cat test_html2.sh
{
  uuencode query5_result.csv query5_result.csv > attachment.txt
  cat mail.html attachment.txt > attachment2.html
} | /usr/lib/sendmail -t abc@abc.com

-----------------------------------------------

3)
cib-sokay2{u384283}324:cat test_html3.sh
export MAILTO="abc@abc.com"
export CONTENT="mail.html"
export CONTENT_F="attachment.txt"
export SUBJECT="TEST EMAIL: TESTING HTML"


BOUNDARY='=== This is the boundary between parts of the message. ==='

{
print -  "From: Someone <$MAILFROM>"
print -  "To: Someone <${MAILTO}>"
print -  'Subject:' $SUBJECT
print -  'MIME-Version: 1.0'
print -  'Content-Type: MULTIPART/MIXED; '
print -  '    BOUNDARY='\"$BOUNDARY\"
print -
print -  '        This message is in MIME format.  But if you can see this,'
print -  "        you aren't using a MIME aware mail program.  You shouldn't "
print -  '        have too many problems because this message is entirely in'
print -  '        ASCII and is designed to be somewhat readable with old '
print -  '        mail software.'
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}"
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=US-ASCII'
print -
cat $CONTENT
print -
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}"
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=US-ASCII; name='${CONTENT}
print -  'Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename='${CONTENT_F}
print -
cat ${CONTENT}
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
} | /usr/lib/sendmail ${MAILTO}

------------------------------------------------------------


cib-sokay2{u384283}326:cat test_html4.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="abc@abc.com"
export CONTENT="mail.html"
export SUBJECT="subject of email"
(
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
# This appears in the mail body
cat $CONTENT
# The next line creates the attachment with a suitable extension to read
# with Windows notepad
unix2dos "attachment.txt" | uuencode myattach.txt
echo "."
) | /usr/lib/sendmail $MAILTO

-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is fairly close.  Your second attempt seems to write something to a file which is then abandoned, and you feed empty input to `sendmail`.  Your third attempt has a grave error in the MIME boundary and some peculiarities (why do you put the same content twice?), but is basically fairly similar to the first.  Your fourth attempt looks fairly reasonable but old-fashioned, but could have failed because of false assumptions about how things need to be formatted (for example, if `$CONTENT` does not start with an empty line, your contents would go smack dab in the message headers, creating illegal headers and probably being rejected).

Assuming you have a command `base64` on your system (it is included in GNU Coreutils since [6.0, almost ten years back](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS#n2877)), just replace the `uuencode` call with that, and fix the various minor formatting errors.  Here is a refactored script which hopefully catches most of them.

```
#!/bin/sh

# No need to export anything, we are not passing these to child processes    
MAILTO="abc@abc.com"
SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
BODY="card_summary_mail.html"
ATTACH="query5_result.csv"

( cat <<____HERE
To: $MAILTO
Subject: $SUBJECT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"

... You could put a MIME preamble here but nobody ever reads it ...

---q1w2e3r4t5
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline
X-Notice: you need an empty line before the body here:

____HERE
 cat "$BODY"
 # also notice empty line at beginning of next snippet
 cat <<____THERE

---q1w2e3r4t5
X-Notice: just "application" is incompletely specified
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="$(basename "$ATTACH")"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$(basename "$ATTACH")"
X-Notice: another empty line

____THERE

 base64 "$ATTACH"

 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/lib/sendmail "$MAILTO"
```

However, assembling your own MIME structure gets tired really fast -- I would recommend looking for a command-line MUA with proper attachment support (`mutt` is popular; some modern `mail`/`mailx` clones have similar facilities, but it's not standard).

Also, there is nothing `ksh`-specific here, so I changed the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is almost correct. Just replace `--base64` by `-m` as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="abc@abc.com"
export SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
export BODY="card_summary_mail.html"
export ATTACH="query5_result.csv"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat "$BODY"
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo 'Content-Type: application; name="'$(basename "$ATTACH")'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename "$ATTACH")'"'
 uuencode -m "$ATTACH" "$(basename "$ATTACH")"
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/lib/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Comment: The `-m` optien to `uuencode` is specified by POSIX, but I would still regard it as esoteric. This still suffers from the lack of an empty line between each body part's headers and its corresponding body.